# Accessing asynchronously loaded object based on relations in Ember

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js

I have a trouble with asynchronously loaded models in Ember. I thought I have already understood the whole "background Ember magic", but I haven't.

I have two models, let's say foo and boo with these properties:

foo: `category: DS.belongsTo("boo", { async: true })`

boo `color: DS.attr("string")`

In my route, I load all `foo`s:

```
model: function(params) {
        return this.store.findAll("task", "");
    },
```

than in my template I render a component: `{{my-component model=model}}`. In the component's code I need to transform the model into another form, so I have:

```
final_data: function() {
        this.get("model").forEach(function(node) {
            console.log(node.get("category"));
        });

        return {};
    }.property("model"),
```

When I try to access the "category" in the model, my code crashes:

```
EmberError@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:25705:15
ember$data$lib$adapters$errors$$AdapterError@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:69218:7
ember$data$lib$adapters$rest$adapter$$RestAdapter<.handleResponse@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:70383:16
ember$data$lib$adapters$rest$adapter$$RestAdapter<.ajax/</hash.error@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:70473:25
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3350:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3462:7
done@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9518:1
.send/callback@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9920:8
```

It seems to me, like the Ember didn't load the `boo`s. How should I access them right to make Ember load them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to load `category`, but the adapter is encountering some error. Can't tell what from your example.

Check your network tab.

Answer (score 0):

When you access an async association from a template, Ember knows what to do. From code, such as your component's logic, Ember has no idea it needs to retrieve the association until you try to `get` it. The `get` will trigger the load, but will return a promise. You can do this:

```
get_final_data: function() {
  Ember.RSVP.Promise.all(this.get("model") . map(node => node.get('category')) 
    .then(vals => this.set('final_data', vals));
}
```

As I'm sure you can see, this creates an array of promises for each node's category, calls `Promise.all` to wait for them all to complete, then stores the result into the `final_data` property.

Note, this is not a computed property; it's a function/method which must be called at some point, perhaps in `afterModel`.